# Transaction governing reading of JMS message and recording it in the DB

Tags: apache-camel, spring-integration

We receive payment messages in our queue. So before processing them and sending them downstream to other queues we have to ensure that a duplicate payment message does not arrive and is processed.

In this case we have JMS and a DB. We want to intercept the payments and ensure that another duplicate is not in the pipeline.

Should this also mean that reading a message and recording that it is being processed should both be wrapped in a XA transaction ?

*Update :*

This http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077963/open-source-tools/distributed-transactions-in-spring--with-and-without-xa.html?page=2 is the most relevant. I haven't read more valuable advice. Is there updated code ?

Should it be full XA since payment is involved ?

Comment: No, you want to use XA since you are accessing multiple resources within the transaction. You want to be sure that if a commit to one of the resources fails, all should fail and rollback

Comment: You mean 'No' ? I think you are advocating XA. I was also interested in Spring integration sample that uses the article's ideas. Can another message and another DB update proceed while the original XA is going on ?

Answer (score 0):

The XA solution is the simplest for your, because you deal with payments. 
So, there is just enough to obtain container's JTA transaction manager and... Everything should work OK. Although you may need to configure your JMS and JDBC DataSources for XA, but may be not. Please, refer to that Dr. Syer article for more information.

From other side, regarding the question about the sample for that article.

There is no so big surprise for that case. You can just follow with the `org.springframework.data.transaction.ChainedTransactionManager` requirements and add JMS and JDBC transaction managers to the chain to proceed 1PC TX properly.

Comment: But 1PC is sufficient for this case ? I think you mean that even if JMS rolls back and the DB commits the next concurrent payment transaction can check the DB ?